# Ubuntu 19.10 Login loop No Solutions working!

Tags: nvidia

Currently I have a problem with a login loop. I’ve searched the internet and nothing has worked so far. I’ve reinstalled GDM3, tried lightdm, tried switch “quiet splash” to “nomodset”. I was able to get in once using startx but even that doesn’t work anymore. I don’t have a lot of experience and really need some help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I gave it a go, but unfortunately, it did not work. I tried a few of the solutions too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. At some point I recall that I also needed to do something like

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Apart from that, deleting and reinstalling gdm3 was that it fixed it. Don't remember the particular order in which I did it.
I think I found the answer in this same forum, but don't remember the particular post...

Comment: I've tried those and I've reinstalled GDM3 many times